# App deployment issues with ParseServer i/o failure

Tags: java, android, parse-server

I have reach a point in my app development where I wanted to test it on an actual device (rather than an emulator). Although the app isn't finished, it works perfectly as it should while running on the emulator.

So I built an APK to transfer to my device and install it. This has all gone well however, when I press a button that runs a ParseQuery to build an array, attach it to a ListView and display in an AlertDialog, all I receive (after a 30-45 seconds) is a toast programmed in as an error handler stating 'i/o failure' - this is the message retrieved from the ParseException.

Unsure about the internet permission requirements regarding ParseServers (it worked fine in the emulator without the internet permission), I tried adding the internet permission to the manifest and tried again... this produced the same result.

I have tried debug and release builds, as well as signed and unsigned APKs all with the same results. With the exception of an unsigned release build that my phone would not install.

I am at a loss with this as it's the first time I have tested an app using ParseServer so I ask all you fine folks if there is any assistance you can provide.

Let me know if there are any specific code segments you need to see and i'll post them but as I say, it works fine in the emulator so I can only assume it's potentially an issue with either the way I build the apk or in the deployment of the ParseServer instance on AWS.

oh.. and i have opted not to use any kind of user authentication with this app as yet so i don't access the user class in any way and automaticuser is enabled.

Code requested @Davi Macêdo - I'm not sure which part of the initialisation you are requesting so I'll add all areas I believe involve setting up Parse for this app -

.StarterApplication -

```
package com.app.letsplaydarts;

import android.app.Application;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class StarterApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .applicationId("9da08bc83....62b73e6ea")
            .clientKey("a04b8e7866a9....67fc3dbebfbd")
            .server("http://ipaddress/parse/")

            .build()
    );

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    defaultACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);


}

}
```

the server address is not the public DNS provided by AWS, it is the reference
 provided by the server.js file accessed through PuTTY following instance creation
 the only public DNS provided is the one for accessing the ParseServer dashboard

I am using the t2.micro free service provided by AWS to host the Bitnami ParseServer

Relevant Project Gradle section -

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()

    }
}
```

Relevant Module Gradle section -

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.17.3'
}
```

PuTTY console results running `curl http://ip/parse/ -v`

```
bitnami@ip-:~$ curl http://ip/parse/ -v
*   Trying ip...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ip (ip) port 80 (#0)
> GET /parse/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: ip
> User-Agent: curl/7.53.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2019 13:24:03 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Parse-Master-Key, X-Parse-REST-API-Key, X-Parse-Javascript-Key, X-Parse-Application-Id, X-Parse-Client-Version, X-Parse-Session-Token, X-Requested-With, X-Parse-Revocable-Session, Content-Type, Pragma, Cache-Control
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Parse-Job-Status-Id, X-Parse-Push-Status-Id
< Content-Length: 24
< Cache-Control: s-maxage=10
<
* Connection #0 to host ip left intact
{"error":"unauthorized"}bitnami@ip:~$
```

I have managed to retrieve some extra information from the ParseException, as follows -

```
.getMessage() returns "I/o failure"
.getCode() returns "100" - Listed as a 'client-only' error
// ConnectionFailed     100     The connection to the Parse servers failed.
.getCause() returns "java.net.UnknownServiceException: CLEARTEXT communication to [ipaddress] not permitted by network security policy"
```

Sounds to me as this may be an issue with my mobile phone network provider!? Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to initialize the Parse SDK and the details about your deployment? Anyway, you might want to make sure that you are using a public IP or DNS to your server and your Security Group allows http/https income connection.

Comment: I have noticed security group sections on the AWS dashboard but as this app is not yet publicly available I haven't looked into any of that yet and the server is on an unsecured http connection

Comment: A quick look at the security groups shows inbound access set for HTTP, SSH and HTTPS

Comment: Can you reach out your parse server api using curl command?

Comment: Again, I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but I have looked into this curl command and ran it on the PuTTY console with the -v command and it does return some version info on the server, but seems it's only partial... I'll add the return to the question, please excuse my lack of understanding of your questions, I'm still new to Android, Java and more so Parse

Comment: I see that you executed from inside the machine that is running Parse Server but I think that your problem is regarding connectivity between your machine and the device. Can you execute the same command from outside the machine (maybe from your personal computer) and receive the same response?

Comment: ah yes, my mistake, I thought it was a parse server command. I have run it from the command prompt on my windows laptop with the exact same output. Any ideas on how to resolve this? As I say, it all works fine when running on the emulator and this is the first time attempting to deploy it.

Comment: Got it. So it looks like that you do not have any connectivity issue. `http://ip/parse/` is the same address that you are using in the app, right? Can you double check the keys that you are using in the app?

Comment: All keys and url are correct, yes. I've just run the app on the emulator again and it is all still working on there.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden - this response has me pondering whether my security groups are setup correctly. I have added All Traffic to the group with no effect but I also noticed the Source property (which appears to be an IP address range) is set to 0.0.0.0/0 - could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance, the `.getCause()` function has proven invaluable. A quick search on the response given by that led me to [this page](https://better-coding.com/solved-android-cannot-send-data-to-the-server-cleartext-communication-to-not-permitted-by-network-security-policy/) - Solution #2 here worked for me, a quick overview below -

add the file "network_security_config.xml" to res\xml\ folder containing -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">your domain or ip address</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

then add the following line to the AndroidManifest.xml -

```
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

rebuild APK and voila!

Thank You @Davi Macêdo for your input, this has been an issue plaguing me for a while now.

It is worth noting that for a final build, Solution #1 may well be more appropriate as it involves the creation of a security certificate and use of the secure https protocols but as this is still in development, the solution above suits my needs perfectly for now.